# Método [Test] não encontrado após build

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Quando faço o *build* do script abaixo, não retorna nenhum erro; no entanto, o build não localiza o método de teste `[Test]`, e não consigo executá-lo.

Meu script é orientado a objetos: chama a classe `massaBase`, a qual lê os dados de um arquivo .txt para fazer inputs e verificações no sistema.

O que pode estar faltando?

```
public Prestador()
{
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

    tiraScreenshot = new capturaImagem(driver);
    CPF = new geraCPF(driver);
    navegador = new acessaSite(driver);
    login = new Login(driver);
    sessao = new sair(driver);
    prestadores = new crudPrestador(driver);
    massa = new massaBase(driver);
}

public void AutomacaoPrestadores(massa.PageObjects.massaBase.DadosTXT coluna)
{
    AutomacaoPrestadores(coluna.usuarioLogin, coluna.senhaLogin, coluna.nomePrestador, coluna.emailPrestador);
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource("ArquivoTXT")]
public void AutomacaoPrestadores(string usuarioLogin, string senhaLogin, string nomePrestador, string emailPrestador)
{
    navegador.acessaURL();
    login.fazLogin(usuarioLogin, senhaLogin);
    prestadores.acessaMenu();
    prestadores.novoCadastro(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.pesquisaPrestador(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.editaPrestador(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.pesquisaPrestador(nomePrestador, emailPrestador);
    prestadores.inativaPrestador(nomePrestador);
    sessao.FazLogoff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questão resolvida com o trecho de código abaixo:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(massaBase), "ArquivoTXT")]
    public void AutomacaoLogin(massaBase.DadosTXT coluna)
```